# VBscript create array but omit blank variables

Tags: arrays, vbscript, compare

I am looking to create a script that will compare the last modified date of up to 4 files then capture the one most recently modified. My current road block is that some files might not exist.

The set will fail if the file does not exist but I can easily overcome that by looking for the file and if it does not exist simply skip the set command. This would cause the creation of the array to fail because my variable is now blank.
Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit  
Dim objFSO, path, file, recentDate, recentFile, File1, File2, File3, File4, afiles, File1date, date1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set File1=objFSO.getfile("c:\temp\file.txt")
set File2=objFSO.getfile("c:\test\File.txt")
set File3=objFSO.getfile("c:\users\%profile%\documents\File.txt")
set File4=objFSO.getfile("c:\users\public\documents\File.txt")

'Prepare variables to store the required information    
Dim dateMin, dateMax
date1 = File1.datelastmodified
wscript.echo date1
wscript.echo now
    dateMin = date1
    dateMax = date1

afiles = Array( File1.datelastmodified, File2.datelastmodified, File3.datelastmodified, File4.datelastmodified )

Dim i
    For i=1 to UBound(aFiles)
        If aFiles(i) < dateMin Then dateMin = aFiles(i)
        if aFiles(i) > dateMax Then dateMax = aFiles(i)
    Next 
'
' Output Information
   WScript.Echo "Highest: " & CStr( dateMax )
   WScript.Echo " Lowest: " & CStr( dateMin )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be much easier if you use an `ArrayList` to capture the `DateLastModified` for each file.
An ArrayList lets you dynamically add values unlike a VBScript Array.
Furthermore, the ArrayList has a very useful method called `Sort()` we can use here to determine the `dateMin` and `dateMax` values.

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO, objList, objFile, arrFiles, fileName

arrFiles = Array("c:\temp\file.txt","c:\test\File.txt","c:\users\%profile%\documents\File.txt","c:\users\public\documents\File.txt")

Set objList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")

For Each fileName In arrFiles
    If objFSO.FileExists(fileName) Then
        Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(fileName)
        objList.Add objFile.DateLastModified
    End If
Next
objList.Sort()

' Prepare variables to store the required information
Dim dateMin, dateMax
dateMin = objList.item(0)
dateMax = objList.item(objList.Count - 1)


' Output Information
WScript.Echo "Highest: " & CStr( dateMax )
WScript.Echo "Lowest:  " & CStr( dateMin )

' Clean up
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objList = Nothing
```

---

**Edit**

The above code was a remake of your original code. I may have misunderstood then that your goal is to find the file most recently modified.

This should do what you have in mind:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO, objFile, objLatest, fileName, arrFiles

arrFiles = Array("c:\temp\file.txt","c:\test\File.txt","c:\users\%profile%\documents\File.txt","c:\users\public\documents\File.txt")

Set objFSO  = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set objLatest = Nothing

For Each fileName In arrFiles
    If objFSO.FileExists(fileName) Then
        Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(fileName)
        If (objLatest Is Nothing) Then
            Set objLatest = objFile
        ElseIf (objFile.DateLastModified > objLatest.DateLastModified) Then
            Set objLatest = objFile
        End If
    End If
Next

If objLatest Is Nothing Then
    WScript.Echo "None of the files in 'arrFiles' exist.."
Else
    ' Here you decide if you want to keep the latest file as Object (-> objLatest) or just as a string to the full pathname of that file
    Dim latestFile
    latestFile = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objLatest)  ' store the full path and filename
    ' Info on FormatDateTime() at https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_formatdatetime.asp
    WScript.Echo "Most recently modified file is '" & latestFile & "' at " & FormatDateTime(objLatest.DateLastModified, 0)
End If

' Clean up
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objLatest = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, it is on the right track. With this I need a variable which will contain the complete path to the most recent file.

Comment: The work I need to do is with the most recent file. The others I will then copy to alternate folders if they exist.

Comment: @MarcB Ah, I didn't quite get that earlier. I have edited my answer and put in new code. Have a look!

Comment: Perfect! That will work for my needs. Thank you so much,

Comment: @MarcB Great, glad to help you. If you liked my answer, please consider accepting it by clicking the outlined checkmark. By accepting, other people that are searching for an answer to a similar question will find it more easily.

Comment: Would you be able to help me expand this script a bit.

Comment: Can you help me expand this script? Here is what I want to add: Search locations for a specific file & add it to the array if found. Eg: Search under c:\users\%profile% for text.txt file. for each one found save the full path in a variable. then do the same for c:\users\public. Once all files are found, find out which is the most recent (which I will copy to a specific location). When all is completed, I would copy all the files found to another location. for example c:\computername\users-public-temp location-file.txt where each word between the dashes would be the path it was found.

Comment: @MarcB I would like to help you, but on holiday right now so all I have here is a phone. It is best if you post this as a new question so others can help you.